# Django extend AbstractUser no such table error

Tags: django, python-3.x, sqlite, django-rest-framework, python-3.8

Im trying to extend django 3.0.1 (drf==3.10.3) AbstractUser, on python 3.8.0.
I'm getting `no such table <appName>_user` error when trying to login on the admin page and with JWT.

My project dir structure:

```sh
root
-|app
--|<projectName>
---|<appName>
---|statics
---|__init__.py
---|settings.py
---|urls.py
---|wsgi.py
---|asgi.py
--|manage.py
--|.env
--|db.sql
```

I've got`__init__.py` on my `app/projectName/appName/migrations` and `app/projectName/appName/tests`.

Here is my relevant parts of `settings.py` file:

```py
BASE_DIR = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(
    os.path.abspath(__file__))), '<projectName>/')

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'drf_yasg',  # openapi

    # local
    '<projectName>.<appName>',
]

if DEBUG:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': env.str('DATABASE_NAME', 'db.sqlite3'),
            'HOST': env.str('DATABASE_HOST', os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3')),
            'PORT': env.int('DATABASE_PORT', '5000')
        },
        'test': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': env.str('DATABASE_NAME', 'testing.sqlite3'),
            'HOST': env.str('DATABASE_HOST', os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'testing.sqlite3')),
            'PORT': env.int('DATABASE_PORT', '5000')
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': env.db(),
    }

AUTH_USER_MODEL = '<appName>.User'
```

Relevant parts of my `appName/models.py`:

```py
class User(AbstractUser):

    role = models.CharField(
        max_length=15,
        choices=[(tag, tag.value)
                 for tag in UserRolesChoise]  # Choices is a list of Tuple
    )
    is_vendor = models.BooleanField(
        _('vendor status'),
        default=False,
        help_text=_(
            'Designates whether the user is a vendor.'),
    )
    is_customer = models.BooleanField(
        _('customer status'),
        default=True,
        help_text=_(
            'Designates whether the user is a customer.'),
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Relevent parts of my `appName/serializers.py`:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'last_login', 'first_name', 'last_name',
                  'get_full_name', 'is_staff', 'is_active', 'date_joined', 'is_vendor', 'is_customer')
```

Relevant parts of my `appName/urls.py`:

```py
from django.urls import path, re_path, include
from django.contrib import admin
from rest_framework import routers
from .<appName> import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/v1/', include(router.urls))
]
```

Relevant parts of my `appName/views.py`:

```py
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import UserSerializer
from .premissions import IsOwnerOrAdmin

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrAdmin,]
```

And relevant parts of my `appName/apps.py`:

```py
from django.apps import AppConfig


class <AppName>Config(AppConfig):
    name = '<appName>'
```

This is a system on development, so i tried removing all migration and DB by running this on my app folder:

```sh
find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "__init__.py" -delete
find . -path "*/migrations/*.pyc"  -delete
rm db.sqlite3
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Strange things:
When I'm running `python manage.py dbshell` and enters `.tables` my `<appname>_user` is being shown.

Some of my tests located at `<appName>/tests/test_*.py` are passing just fine:

```py
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()


class UserModelTestCase(APITestCase):
    """ Test module for User model """

    def setUp(self):
        super(UserModelTestCase, self).setUp()
        self.given_user_exists(first_name='Test', last_name='Customer', email="customer@gmail.com",  password="7789",
            username="Test Customer", role='Customer')
        self.given_user_exists(
            first_name='Test', last_name='Vendor', email="vendor@gmail.com", password="7789",
            username="Test Vendor",
            role='Vendor', is_vendor=True, is_customer=False)
        self.given_user_exists(
            first_name='Test', last_name='Staff', email="stff@gmail.com", password="7789",
            username="Test Staff",
            role='Admin', is_customer=False, is_staff=True)

        self.user_customer=User.objects.get(username='Test Customer')
        self.user_vendor=User.objects.get(username='Test Vendor')
        self.user_staff=User.objects.get(username='Test Staff')

    def tearDown(self):
        super(UserModelTestCase, self).tearDown()

    def test_all_users_hidden_for_anonymous_users(self):
        all_users = self.client.get('/api/v1/users/')
        self.assertEqual(all_users.status_code,status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

All of the  and  on my code written without the<>.

It makes me think it's a DB issue, but i don't understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to move on with this project, so i did the less smart thing i could think about - run away form the issue, which i'm now sure is a settings issue.

If it's gonna help some one, here is what i did:

1. I created a new root for the project.
2. Inside of this folder i ran `python manage.py start app <appName>` for creating my apps. Here is my current files:

```sh
root
-|<projectName>
--|<projectName>
---|__init__.py
---|settings.py
---|urls.py
---|wsgi.py
---|asgi.py
--|<appName>
---|apps.py
---|views.py
---|_init__.py
---|serializers.py
---|etc...
--|statics
--|manage.py
--|.env
--|db.sql
```

3. Removed db.sql file, migrations and `__pycache__` folders.
4. Copied the relevant code pieces from the original folder.
5. Changed settings and imports according the new projects.

**TL;DR**
Once i created the new project structure, removed migration, `__pycache__` folders and DB file, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Please check **User** model for having `abstract = True` in Meta class. Remove this line if present.

If it has abstract = True attribute this model will then not be used to create any database table. Looking like in your case.

Comment: All of my user model written above. I do not have any abstract property.

Comment: Yes, i see. If you check django User model which is inherited from AbstractUser too, you can see `class Meta(AbstractUser.Meta): swappable = 'AUTH_USER_MODEL'` Could you please try to add this class like in /django/contrib/auth/models.py in django package?

Comment: Adding this:
`class Meta(AbstractUser.Meta):
        swappable = 'AUTH_USER_MODEL'
        abstract=False`
Into my model.py user did not help.

Comment: It seems the problem is in UserCreationForm which you haven't overwritten. UserCreationForm contains User model from django.contrib.auth.models.

Comment: Pls correct me if i'm wrong, but the UserCreationForm being used (on my case) only at the admin login page.
This error appears also at the JWT login (I'm using django-rest-framework).

Comment: Sorry for not being reachable for a long time. I was not able to reproduce the error. But I got this error only when I removed AUTH_USER_MODEL from settings.py after all the migrations was applied. I believe the issue is around migrations. Could you please try to remove all your app migrations and the test database then make migrations again avoiding AUTH_USER_MODEL modification.

Comment: Thank You!
I did reset all the migrations, as I wrote on the question. It didn't help. I'm really close of giving up and re-setup the whole environment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your own `BaseUserManager` as well. Add below code at your `models.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I added the manager (though i really don't understand what it's got to do with getting list of users or authenticate - the createsuperuser function works fine), and added `objects = UserManager()` into the user model on models.py and it didn't work.
I also tried changing the manager name to MyUserManager to avoid overriding, and it didn't help. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A viable solution might be to just delete the db.sql file and run the commands to make migrations and migrate.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).